# Forcing 404 error in the right way in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

So I have 404.html in my public folder. And I have controller with something like

```
def show
  @info = Info.find_by_id params[:id]
  render :file => 'public/404.html', :status => 404 if @info.nil?
end
```

But this `render :file => 'public/404.html', :status => 404` seems rather unclean. Is there better way? Something like `raise Error::404`